# Why my CallBack function doesnt works?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to make some calls to a WebService

I did exactly what is described in this article

http://viralsarvaiya.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/calling-web-service-from-java-script-in-asp-net-c/

Looking at the console of firebug I could see that my function was executed and returned the expected data, but my callback functions (OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut) are never executed.

Whats wrong?

Here is the code (same code of the article)
Service.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://Localhost...xys/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components
    //InitializeComponent();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string strNoOfData)
    {
        return strNoOfData;
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function CallService() {
    Service.HelloWorld(document.getElementById('Textbox1').value,
        OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
}

function OnComplete(Text) {
    alert(Text);
}

function OnTimeOut(arg) {
    alert("timeOut has occured");
}

function OnError(arg) {
    alert("error has occured: " + arg._message);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<fieldset>
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Call Service" OnClientClick="CallService()" />
</fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please post your code here? that might help debugging the issue.

Comment: the code is EXACTLY the code of the article

Comment: I used your exact code, callbacks called as expected. The only thing i noticed is you are passing `OnTimeOut` in place of `userContext` parameter, try adding `InlineScript="true"` to your service reference then view source and check the generated service script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the project type, it works in WebApplication, not in WebSites

Comment: Glad you found out. Also, you should move away from ASMX services and begin using WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Im a VB guy mostly so ....

Try one at a time in order.

First see if you are really selecting the textbox, I doubt it. Set the ClientIDMode to be static.

Second try  `[WebMethod(), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)]`

Third make the method static .. oops virtual and the class also.